# csplit regex multiple digits between "[" and "]"

Tags: linux, bash, csplit

I want to split txt file on string "Template[0]", "Template[1]" etc.

The command below works until "Template[10]"

```
csplit -k cert_templates.txt '/Template\[[0-9]\]:/' {*}
```

I tried those but they did'nt work

```
csplit -k cert_templates.txt '/Template\[([0-9]+)\]:/' {*}

csplit -k cert_templates.txt '/Template\[[0-9]+\]:/' {*}
```

This works for "Template[10]" + until "Template[100]"

```
csplit -k cert_templates.txt '/Template\[[0-9][0-9]\]:/' {*}
```

What regex should i use to work with undefined number of digits?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: When `+` does not work, the usual fallback is `[0-9][0-9]*`

Answer (score 0):

This regex will suffice: `^\d+$`

To break this down, the `\d` means any digit and the `+` means one or more.

Comment: sadly 'csplit -k cert_templates.txt '/Template\[^\d+$\]:/' {*}' does not work. csplit returns whole file

Answer (score 0):

The regex flavor used by this `csplit` requires that '+', if it is to match a sequence of 1 or more, is preceded by a backslash, i. e. `Template\[[0-9]\+\]`.